# Take action from extended event?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, service-broker, extended-events

I've seen it mentioned a few times that you can [configure an event session to take an action when an event fires.](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/why-use-sql-server-extended-events-w01/#.VQM5HWjF_ON) Does anyone have any information on how to do this?  I know that you can use the service broker to take an action on an event, but I don't consider that to be part of an event session.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm familiar with such a capability (assuming you're referring to this statement, "In fact, it’s even possible to purposely configure an Extended Events session to stop SQL Server when a specific event occurs; it’s that powerful!"). I know that Jason Strate put together something that leverages Service Broker:
http://sqlmag.com/site-files/sqlmag.com/files/archive/sqlmag.com/content/content/142603/wpd-sql-extevtandnotif-us-sw-01112012_1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[Erin Stellato's Stairway to Extended Events](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/134877/) is a good starting point here (it's behind a registration wall, but it's worth it.) She explains how you can use the SSMS GUI to create an Extended Events session that will trigger a dump, for example.

Understand that taking an action like creating a dump will be very performance-intensive.